# Rails3: Gem Gmap4rails with mongoid doesn't show map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, gmaps4rails

I followed the instruction on github to install everything. 
([Gmaps4Rails-github](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails))

The problem is that the map is blank, I only see the border of the map from the css.

Model:

```
class Recipe
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable
  acts_as_gmappable 

  field :name, :type => String
  field :city, :type => String
  field :country, :type => String
  field :latitude, :type => Float
  field :longitude, :type => Float
  field :gmaps, :type => Boolean

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.city}, #{self.country}" 
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @location = Recipe.all.to_gmaps4rails
  end
end
```

View:

```
= gmaps4rails(@location)
```

@location has the lat and lng in an array like

```
[{"lat":13.055363,"lng":47.811886},{"lat":13.055363,"lng":47.811886}]
```

The required JS and CSS files are getting loaded:
gmaps4rails.base.js, gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js, gmaps4rails.bing.js, gmaps4rails.mapquest.js, gmaps4rails.openlayers.js, gmaps4rails.css

I don't get any errors in the server log or in the JS console. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Any suggestion would be really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any mention of:

```
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

in your code here. This is mandatory though!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it would be enough to load the required js files through the Rails asset pipeline.